# hive "with tbl as" vs "create table tbl as"

Tags: hive, hql

1. Does < **with tbl as** > much faster than < **create table tbl as** > ?

```sql
   with tbl as 
   (
    select 
      id,name 
    from 
      a
   )
   select id from tbl;

   create table tbl 
   as 
   select 
      id,name 
   from 
      a;

   select id from tbl;
```

2. If I want use tbl in many querys, how to use < **with tbl as** >?

```sql
    with tbl as 
   (
    select 
      id,name 
    from 
      a
   )
   select id from tbl;

   select name from tbl;
```

Comment: You could compare between the two execution by adding EXPLAIN at the begging of each query this will give you the time of execution of each query

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/13117/141721

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There's no obvious performance gap.
2. `with tbl as` is a common table expression, aka CTE, which is only accessible within a single query. So we CAN NOT use CTE across multiple SQL queries separated by `;`.
3. Favor `create temporary table` table over `create table`. The former is visible within a single session, and will be gone when the session ends.